# how to render html to bitmap AND output hyperlink region?

Tags: html, webbrowser-control, render

There are many ways to render a html page to a bitmap, but in my case, I need to output all hyperlink region (rect, polygon or some other simple shapes) as well as the url. What is the simplest way to achieve this? Techniques based on .net, java, or C++/Qtwebkit are preferred, thanks.